# A Fortran analog to python's super()?

Tags: python, fortran

When working with classes and in particular with extended types in Fortran 2003/8: 
is there any analog of python's super() function that can be used to call a method from the extending type which has been overridden in the extended type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, if the parent type is not abstract.

```
CALL object%ParentType%Binding(...)
```

Otherwise you can always just call the specific procedure that implements the binding in the parent.

Comment: Thank you! Works where "ParentType" is the name of the actual parent type.