# "Extending" a function in a Fortran derived type

Tags: inheritance, fortran, derived-types

I say "extending" because, forgive me, I'm not sure what the correct OOP terminology here is.  I do not exactly want to override a function.  I want a function in an inheriting derived type to do all of the work that the function of the same name does in the parent type, and then add to that.  I want something like:

```
module foo1
  type :: bar1
  contains
    procedure :: f1
  end type bar1
contains
  subroutine bar1()
  ! do stuff
  end subroutine bar1
end module foo1

module foo2
  use foo1
  type, extends(bar1) :: bar2
  contains
    procedure :: f1
  end type bar2
contains
  subroutine f1()
    ! call parent f1
    ! do other stuff
  end subroutine f1
end module foo2
```

Is there a way to do this in Fortran?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004208/a-fortran-analog-to-pythons-super

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must do normal overriding and inside the new procedure you have to call the parent type procedure manually (in a way linked in a comment by ptb [A Fortran analog to python's super()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004208/a-fortran-analog-to-pythons-super)).

```
subroutine f1(self)
  call self%bar1%f1 
  !the rest
end subroutine
```

Comment: Just what I needed.  Thanks!